# Android Layout: Button gets moved when Keyboard pops up

Tags: android, android-layout

My Layout gets changed when the keyboard pops up.
Specifically, the register Button gets moved upwards and rests on top of one of the EditTexts.
I want my view to stay the same size and be able to scroll it in the smaller viewport when my keyboard is open.
I've tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" (Button gets moved) and "adjustPan" (Button doesn not get moved, but to see the Button, you first have to close the keyboard)

I have following xml-file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/register_header"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ... />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           ... />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/register_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/register_header"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        // Bunch of EditText's here


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/register_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <Button 
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/register_button_register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/register" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a RelativeLayout as the child of the ScrollView, use a LinearLayout like this

```
<ScrollView>
     <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
       <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
         <EditTexts />
       </LinearLayout>
       <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
```

When you have a RelativeLayout and a child with alignParentBottom=true, that child will always be at the bottom of the screen which in the adjustResize case means above the keyboard and over the EditTexts.

Answer (score 3):

put this in your manifest under "the" activity tag

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

for more info [keyboard](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)

Comment: adjustNothing is not a attribute in the Android API, I also read some posts where it is used, but it may be dangerous because of different devices and their different handling....

Comment: unfortunately, while this solves the problem of the button getting moved, it also doesn't allow me to scroll the content when the keyboard is visible. In that regard it behaves like `adjustPan`